# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'call' backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript

This is happening after I do an edit to a model. It sends the request (I have that turned on in chrome and I see it log externally) but when it gets a response, that error pops up.

Here's my model:

```
Investments.EmergingModel = Backbone.Model.extend
  idAttribute: "id_number"

  initialize: ->
    _.bindAll this

  url: ->
    u = "#{Investments.Options.rootUrl}fleets/#{Investments.Options.fleet}/emerging_technology_vehicles"
    u = "#{Investments.Options.rootUrl}fleets/#{Investments.Options.fleet}/emerging_technology_vehicles/#{this.id}" if this.id
    u
```

let me know if you need anymore code..

Comment: What's the stack trace look like, where does it intersect your own code?  Also this is a class, but you have not instantiated it or called any methods on it, so what is the action you take on instances of this class that causes this error to appear.  Lastly, if you can recreate the issue in a small example on http://jsfiddle.net you will get more help.

Comment: @AlexWayne Well, the stack trace never does intersect my code: http://cloud.jtmkrueger.com/image/3D47371j0R1a

Comment: @AlexWayne I'll add some view code, good idea!

Comment: Dang. Well it's impossible to debug this with the info provided. What's that jQuery event, how it is bound, and to what function on what object? Help us help you, dude.

Comment: I've isolated it to a listenTo call in a view... I'll try on posting something when I find the culprit.

Comment: @thatmiddleway Based on the stack trace, I think you are calling `listenTo/on` with an object instead of a function. Typo somewhere?

Comment: @loganfsmyth yes, doh! it was a -> instead of a =>